# Convert `@UsingDataSet` to `@Sql`

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, jboss-arquillian

I'm migrating an application from Thorntail to Spring Boot.

Some of our integration tests are using Arquillian and its `@UsingDataSet` annotation, that -- very conveniently -- lets you specify data structures in yaml.

Sadly, I don't think SpringBoot supports "yaml-injections", but it *does* provide an `@Sql` annotation that expects -- suprise -- sql files.

Now I don't want to rewrite the test data in SQL. It's cumbersome and I have zero desire to spend hours debugging SQL because I slipped up somewhere down the line.

Ideally, of course, we would get rid of the yaml/sql files entirely and opt for, say, jOOQ and fill our test database from within the code.

Not sure yet if that would be doable with reasonable effort, though.

Let's assume rewriting in code is not an option and we have an integration test like so

```
@RunWith(Arquillian::class)
@UsingDataSet("foo.yml","bar.yml","baz.yml")
class MyBloodyIT{
}
```

I should like to create an auxiliary "test" class

```
@RunWith(Arquillian::class)
class MyBloodySQLDumpIT{

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet("foo.yml")
    fun dumpFoo(){
        // dump hibernate-generated SQL statements to `foo.sql`
    }

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet("bar.yml")
    fun dumpFoo(){
        // dump hibernate-generated SQL statements to `bar.sql`
    }

    @Test
    @UsingDataSet("baz.yml")
    fun dumpFoo(){
        // dump hibernate-generated SQL statements to `baz.sql`
    }
}
```

How do I *do* that, though?

Any way to hook into hibernate and get the statements generated for a specific method(and the statements only and only for that one method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does Arquillian have to do with Hibernate? I think it uses DBUnit to seed the database from YAML.

What you can do is use the **p6spy** (https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) JDBC driver, run a mock test for each YAML file and get all the SQL statements from the p6spy logs.